# how to change a char to a boolean?

Tags: java, char, boolean, setter, getter

my question is how to change a char to a boolean. for example i have 2 class

one is patient class with only bleedinghistory method and info:

```
Public class Patient {

        private static String name;
        private static boolean bleedingHistory = true;
        private String answer;
        private double ureaLevel;
        private double proLevel;


        public Patient()
        {
            String name = "unknown";
            double ureaLevel = 0.0;
            double proLevel = 0.0;
            boolean bleedingHistory = false;

        }

        public Patient (String inName, boolean inBleedingHistory)
        {
            if (name != "" || bleedingHistory == true)
            {
                name = inName;
                bleedingHistory = inBleedingHistory;

            }

            else
            {
                name = "unknown";
                bleedingHistory = false;    
            }

            proLevel = 0.0;
            ureaLevel = 0.0;
        }
    public boolean getBleedingHistory()
            {
                return bleedingHistory;

            }

            public void setBleedingHistory(boolean inBleedingHistory)
            {

                bleedingHistory = inBleedingHistory;
            }
```

and a part of another class call patientcheck that ask the user to enter whether the patient has history of bleeding:

```
System.out.print("Does the patient has a history of bleeding(Yes or No)?: ");
        char inBleedingHistory; 
        do 
        {
            inBleedingHistory = sc.next().charAt(0);
            if (inBleedingHistory != 'n' && inBleedingHistory != 'N' && inBleedingHistory != 'y' && inBleedingHistory != 'Y')
            {System.out.println("Invalid answer, please enter YES or NO: ");

            sc.nextLine();
            }

        }while (inBleedingHistory != 'n' && inBleedingHistory != 'N' && inBleedingHistory != 'y' && inBleedingHistory != 'Y');

        pat1 = new Patient (inName, inBleedingHistory);
```

i know my patientcheck part for history bleeding is wrong but what can i do to correct it? thanks

Comment: `boolean charIsY = (ch=='y' || ch=='Y');`

Answer (score 1):

```
pat1 = new Patient(inName, (inBleedingHistory=='y' || inBleedingHistory=='Y'));
```

Comment: oh so i can do this? i never thought about that

Comment: Yes you can. Please accept the answer if it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
pat1 = new Patient (inName, Character.toString(inBleedingHistory).equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
```

this will return true if inBleedingHistory matches y or Y. It will also convert the Char to a String before comparing.

You can also cast it to a String using

```
pat1 = new Patient (inName, String.valueOf(inBleedingHistory).equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
```

which is the same.

You can also compare Chars which may be the fastest way.

```
Character yesLower, yesUpper;

yesLower = new Character('y');
yesUpper = new Character('Y');

pat1 = new Patient (inName, (inBleedingHistory.compareTo(yesLower ) == 0 || inBleedingHistory.compareTo(yesUpper) == 0));
```

Comment: Could also use `equalsIgnoreCase` to count for y/Y differences.

Comment: You have to use `==` on `char`, not `equals`

Comment: fixed it. cast to string or use a string instead.

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold, I think the problem is that `inBleedingHistory` is a char so has no `equalsIgnoreCase` method

Comment: whops, now i got it. :-) Sorry, didnt see it. Had no coffee today ;)